# interactive graph in R

Tags: r, graph, zooming, shiny, interactive

I'd like to create interactive graphs in R where the user can zoom in/out of the graph, and if possible also to click on a vertex and get more information about it. In igraph, there is rglplot, which can zoom in and out, but makes the graph 3d - if there is a way to make an rglplot appear 2d, that might do the trick. igraph also has tkplot, but that only allows one to drag the vertices, not zoom in / out. Also tkplot can't be deployed on the web (which is preferred but not a requirement).

I have read that ragraph can plot interactive graphs, but haven't been able to figure out how.

Does anyone have any good suggestions?

Comment: @jalapic - thanks for your reply, I think I can do a lot with svg. I'm not sure though if I should use gridSVG or SVGAnnotation. gridSVG as I understand is compatible with Shiny, but must be used on grid-based plots - I have a graph object (a graphNEL graph) which is plotted with the base plot() - is that a grid-based plot / can I apply grid to it? SVGAnnotation works with base graphics, but do you know if its compatible with Shiny?

Comment: Thanks everyone, - this is working fine for some of my smaller graphs, but for the bigger ones, it is crashing r studio. @jalapic networkD3 may be better for larger graphs, but does it support directed acyclic graphs? Something like this: https://github.com/nickholub/d3-dag-visualization, but is also supported in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very good option is the `svgPanZoom` package, which is essentially a R htmlwidget for `svg-pan-zoom.js`

you can use it with regular plots, other graphing packages and shiny.

see:  https://github.com/timelyportfolio/svgPanZoom

example:

```
devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/svgPanZoom") #install


library(svgPanZoom) 
library(SVGAnnotation)

svgPanZoom(
  svgPlot(
    plot(1:10)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out Shiny. It lets you create very neat interactive graphs and easily deploy them to a web page. Note that it is completely dependent on RStudio. I've played with it a bit and was pretty impressed. They have good tutorials.
http://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/

Comment: thanks Danny. Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for. I have an app in Shiny but I can only interact with plots through user controls - i.e. I can have a user type in a control and show all nodes below. But I can't have the user click on a node to show more info, or just zoom in zoom out with a mouse, for example

Comment: @md1630 - take a look at networkD3 - that enables you to interact more with network graphs